# C++ WinSnmp callback func and object address in lpClientData parameter

Tags: c++, winapi, winsnmp

My c++ class is using WinSnmp to get integer value from device. 
The session is initialized as follows:

```
snmpident::snmpident(const char* c, const char* si, const char* i,const char* o)
{...
sesshandle=SnmpCreateSession(NULL,NULL,snmpgetCB,this);
...}
```

So, i'm receiving address of class object in callback function, that is using it to call method of this object:

```
SNMPAPI_STATUS CALLBACK snmpgetCB(HSNMP_SESSION hSession,HWND hWnd,  //callback func
    UINT wMsg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam,LPVOID lpClientData)
{...
reinterpret_cast<snmpident*>(lpClientData)->recv(sv.value.sNumber); //recv is an "snmpident" class method
...}
```

As you can see, it can cause "access violation" if the user of the class (in this case I) removes the class object before the callback function completes its work.
How can i fix this?
Sleep() looks ugly. Array of {pointer;session id} structure looks bit intresting, but i'm not sure, that it's the best choice.

P.S. Please forgive me for my english.

Comment: Make `snmpindent` a singleton and have one global instance of it.

Comment: You could alternatively use messages as your callback mechanism. If the associated window is destroyed prior to the message arriving you will not get an acces violation. To do so you can create a message only window and attach your `snmpident` object to this window (the Extra Window Memory is probably a good place to store this information).

Comment: Close the SNMP session before destroying your class object.

Comment: Snmp session is closing in the destructor. But the callback function may already be running. Using another window for messages looks interesting, thanks.